# Synchronization protocol for server and many offline clients

Tags: wcf, timestamp, changeset, data-synchronization

I am working on a web service, that can be accessed by web site and by mobile clients without permanent internet connection.

The idea is to have synchronized database on the internet and also on all clients. When the user changes data on a mobile client, it is flagged as changed in local db. When the user updates data on a website, the changeset in online DB is increased. After the synchronization, the clients remember changeset of their actual data. The problem is, when I change the data on one client, and then on another client and then I trigger the syncronization, the web server does not know, which data are the last.

Here is an example how it currently works:

1. Lets say that everything is synchronized on the beginning. - data is "A"
2. First client changes the data and flags it as changed. - data is changed to "B" in client local db
3. Second client changes the data and flags it as changed - data is changed to "C" in local db
4. First client goes online and updates the online database (text is now "B"). The changeset in online DB is increased.
5. Second client goes online, detects new changeset in online DB and downloads new data (local "C" is rewritten with online "B") (text is now "B")
6. Everything is now synchronized, but text is "B" instead of "C"

I think the problem is in step 6. The client knows, that there is both a local and an online change, but it is not able to decide what is the correct value.

Could you please help me, how to solve this problem? I was thinking about timestamps instead of changesets, but I can not ensure that all clients have correct time.

PS: The server runs WCF service with MSSQL and clients are ASP.NET website and Andorid and WP7 smartphones. It is not able to save any information about clients in online db. I expect the client synchronization to be run +/- once a day.

I hope my question is understandable :)
Thanks.